# Trace the caller React component from some imported Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have React components created with classes extending Component. This components imports ES6 classes (generic, not React ones). I want to know from some of the methods of this Es6 classes whith React Component called them.

Is it possible?
I tried to use the javascript stack trace:

```
    var err = new Error();
    return err.stack;
}
```

But it doesn't work enough good, especially with build code.

Is there any cleaner solution in React? Maybe some React method or library?

Thanks.